How to show that conserved charge in BRST quantization is zero when acting on physical states?
I consider the following physical state
$$
\begin{align}
|\text{phys}\rangle&\propto \quad (a^{+\dagger}_{k_1})^{n(k_1,+)} \ldots (a^{+\dagger}_{k_N})^{n(k_N,+)} (a^{-\dagger}_{q_1})^{n(q_1,-)} \ldots (a^{-\dagger}_{q_M})^{n(q_M,-)} \\
&\times \quad (b^{\dagger}_{\tilde{k}_1})^{n(\tilde{k}_1)} \ldots (b^{\dagger}_{\tilde{k}_\tilde{N}})^{n(\tilde{k}_\tilde{N})} (d^{\dagger}_{\tilde{q}_1})^{n(\tilde{q}_1)} \ldots (d^{\dagger}_{\tilde{q}_\tilde{M}})^{n(\tilde{q}_\tilde{M})} |0\rangle
\end{align}
$$
Here $a^{+\dagger}_{k}$ create with photons with right handed polarization and $a^{-\dagger}_{k}$ create with photons with left handed polarization. The operators of $b^{\dagger}_{k}$ and $d^{\dagger}_{k}$ create fermions and anti-fermions respectively.
Now I can show that the BRST conserved current is:
\begin{aligned}
Q_{B} & =\int d^3 x j_{B}^0 \\
& =\int d^3 x\left\{-F^0_{\text{ }\text{ }\nu} \partial^v c-(\partial . A) \partial_t c-e \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0} \psi c\right\}\\
&=\int d^3 x\left\{-F^0_{\text{ }\text{ }\nu} \partial^v c-(\partial . A) \partial_t c\right\}+\int d^3 x\left\{- \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0} \psi c\right\}\\
&=Q_{1}+Q_{2}
\end{aligned}
Furthermore, the $Q_{1}$ charge can be explicitly calculated to get:
$$\begin{aligned} Q_{1} 
& =-\int d^3 x\left[F^{0 \nu} \partial_\nu c+(\partial \cdot A) \partial^0 c\right]\\
&= -\int \frac{d^3 \vec{k}}{(2\pi)^3} \sqrt{2} k_0\left\{a_{\vec{k}}^{<}c^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}}+a_{\vec{k}}^{<\dagger}c_{\vec{k}}\right\}\\
\end{aligned}$$
Here the $c_{\vec{k}}$ operators are from the Fourier modes of the anti-commuting ghost fields. Now $Q_{1}$ only has unphysical polarization annihilation operators and unphysical ghost annihilation operators, which implies
$$\implies Q_{1}|\text{phys}\rangle  =0$$
Now $Q_2$ takes the form
$$
\begin{align}
Q_{Dirac}&=\int d^3x j_{Dirac}^{0}\\
& =-\int d^3 xe \bar{\psi} \gamma^{0} \psi c\\
&=-e\int d^3 x \psi^{\dagger} \psi c \\ 
&=-e\int \frac{d^3 x \text{ }d^3 p \text{ }d^3 q \text{ }d^3 k}{\left((2 \pi)^3\right)^3} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{8 \text{ } p_0 \text{ } k_0 \text{ }q_0}} \sum_{s, t} \\ 
&\times\left(a_{\bar{p}}^{s\dagger} u^{s\dagger}(\bar{p}) e^{i p x}+b_{\bar{p}}^s v^{s\dagger}(\bar{p}) e^{-i p x}\right)\\
&\times\left(a_{\bar{q}}^t u^t(\bar{q}) e^{-i q x}+b_{\bar{q}}^{t\dagger} v^t(\bar{q}) e^{i q x}\right) \\ 
&\times \left(e^{-i k x} c(\bar{k})+e^{i k x} c^{t\dagger}(\bar{k})\right)
\end{align}
$$
I am however not able to show that $Q_{2}|\text{phys}\rangle  =0$. Does anyone perhaps know how?

Suggestion to the post (v2): Consider to include relevant reference(s)?
